# Armadillo library not found when importing python package (OS X, Python 2.7)

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, boost

I'm working with a python package (carmcmc) that depends on Boost, Armadillo. I'm getting the following error:

```
import carmcmc

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carmcmc/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _carmcmc import *

ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carmcmc/_carmcmc.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.5.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carmcmc/_carmcmc.so
```

It seems that lib armadillo.5.dylib is missing, but I don't know what it does or how I would amend its absence.

I installed as such:

1. Installed Armadillo dependencies using homebrew
2. Installed Armadillo with homebrew
3. Installed Boost
4. Installed Boost-python
5. Ran setup.py install for the package

setup.py ran with a few exceptions, but nothing fatal that I caught.

Is this a version issue? Am I still missing dependencies? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you check if you have a file called /usr/local/lib/libarmadillo*

Comment: As it turns out, I have a file with a version number appended to the end of it. I uninstalled, reinstalled manually because home-brew didn't have the earlier version I needed, and during install the library wasn't created. So I'm still stuck at the same place with the same problem.

Comment: usually it is possible (if backward compatbility is supported) to simply link the file so install it from brew than link /usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.dylib to /usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.5.dylib

Answer (score 1):

Here what i did:

1. install armadillo from brew - brew install homebrew/science/armadillo
2. isntall boost from brew - brew install boost boost-python
3. git clone git@github.com:brandonckelly/carma_pack.git
4. mkvirtual env
5. installed numpy from pip - pip install numpy
6. exported variables

   - export BOOST_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0
   - export ARMADILLO_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/6.100.0
   - export NUMPY_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.58.0/ # becouse it was easier than actually pass the correct location
7. run python setup.py install in the src folder for carma_pack

it is now installed (however i did have to install matplotlib inorder for it to work)

also the code for carmac has install instructions for osx